# Apollo GraphQL query overwrites subelement array with other query

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have two queries fetching the category types of a company.
The employee query includes a subset of types of the company query types in the database.
If I just query the employee query, the employee types array includes 2 elements.
If I just query the company query, the company types array includes 4 elements.
Well..
But if i query both, the types array of employee gets updated and suddenly includes 4 elements instead of 2.

```
query GetEmployee ($id: ID!) {
employee (id: $id) {
  id,
  companyTaskCategories{
      id,
      title,
      color,
      archived,
      types(restrictEmployee: true)  {
        id,
        title,
        archived,
      }
  }
}


query company {
company {
  id,
  taskCategories {
    id,
    title,
    color,
    archived,
    types(restrictEmployee: false) {
      id,
      title,
      archived,
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you have implemented your resolver functions, but if you want to run two queries and get isolated results then please use mutations as it will ensure your queries doesn't create race conditions at the backend.

So please use mutation to fetch data sequentially.

As stated in http://graphql.org/learn/queries/

> While query fields are executed in parallel, mutation fields run in
>   series, one after the other.

Comment: Actually the problem is, that apollo merges the responses of the types subelement but the employee types is a filtered subset of the company types array. Apollo assumes, that elements have been added and automatically overwrites the whole employee types array. Not only the existing elements get updated, but also the whole array length changes by adding the new elements from the company call